# Does $|(X\times\{0\}) \cup (X\times\{1\})| \leq |X|$ for $X$ infinite imply ${\sf AC}$?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

Consider the statement

> > For any infinite set $X$ there is an injection $\varphi$ from $(X\times\{0\}) \cup (X\times\{1\})$ into $X$.

Does this imply the ${\sf AC}$?

Comment: Also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/393196/622 and other questions on the "Linked" menu to the right in that link.

Comment: There's probably a question about this on this site as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's way over my head, but it seems that this question was answered in the negative by Gershon Sageev, An independence result concerning the axiom of choice, Ann. Math. Logic 8 (1975), 1-184.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: So the statement is strictly "in between" ${\sf ZF}$ and ${\sf ZFC}$ it appears...