# Some very weak statements on choice

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

This is a follow-up question to [Does $|(X\times\{0\}) \cup (X\times\{1\})| \leq |X|$ for $X$ infinite imply ${\sf AC}$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/230260/does-x-times-0-cup-x-times-1-leq-x-for-x-infinite-imply-s)

Consider the statements

> > $(\text{S}1)$ For any infinite set $X$ there is an injection $\varphi$ from $(X\cup\{X\})$ into $X$.

and

> > $(\text{S}2)$ For any infinite set $X$ there is an injection $\varphi$ from $(X\times\{0\}) \cup (X\times\{1\})$ into $X$.

Is it true that ${\sf ZF} < {\sf ZF}+(\text{S1}) < {\sf ZF}+(\text{S}2)$? (Here $<$ means "strictly weaker".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$S1$ is equivalent to "every infinite set is Dedekind-infinite", so $\sf ZF<ZF+(S1)$, because it is consistent that infinite Dedekind-finite sets exist.

$\sf ZF+(S1)<ZF+(S2)$ follows using results from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393196/the-relationship-of-frak-mm-m-to-ac), which implies that $\sf DC_\kappa$ doesn't imply $S2$, and hence nonexistence of infinite Dedekind-finite sets, which is a corollary to $\sf DC(=DC_\omega)$.